# Quitar duplicado

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo en JavaScript y quisiera saber donde radica el error, necesito imprimir valores no repetidos o si conocen alguna forma mas eficaz:

```
 var t1  = 2;
 var t2 = 2;
 var t3 = 3;

 var t4 = [t1,t2,t3];
 var t5 = t4.unique();
 console.log(t5);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El array en JavaScript no tiene función `unique`.

Si estás usando ES5, podés hacer lo siguiente:

```
function unique(value, index, self) { 
   return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var t1 = 2;
var t2 = 2;
var t3 = 3;

var t4 = [t1,t2,t3];
var t5 = t4.filter(unique);
console.log(t5);
```

Si estás usando ES6, podés hacer lo siguiente:

```
var t1 = 2;
var t2 = 2;
var t3 = 3;

var t4 = [t1,t2,t3];
var t5 = t4.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
console.log(t5);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias federico se me habia olvidado pegar la funcion pero ya pude ver el error

Answer (score 1):

A partir de **[ECMAScript 6](http://es6-features.org/#SetDataStructure)** puedes utilizar la estructura de datos: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set)

```
[...new Set([1, 2, 2])]
```